# problems with .live and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".vote, .vote1").click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this);

        if(name=='mod_up')
        {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mod_up_vote.php",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(xml)
                {
                    //$("#mod-pregunta").html(html);
                    //$("#mod-respuesta").html(html);
                    //parent.html(html);
                    $(xml).find('pregunta').each(function()
                    {
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var pregunta = $(this).find('preguntadato').text();
                        var respuesta = $(this).find('respuestadato').text();
                        var votoup = $(this).find('votoup').text();
                        var votodown = $(this).find('votodown').text();
                        var id_pregunta = $(this).find('id_pregunta').text();
                        var id_respuesta = $(this).find('id_respuesta').text();
                        $("#mod-pregunta").html(pregunta);
                        $("#mod-respuesta").html(respuesta);
                        $(".vote1").html("<a href=\"\" title=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-1\" class=\"vote1\" id=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-1\" name=\"mod_up\">Aceptar</a>");
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

With this link, It update the database and show a new question and answer.

```
<a href="" title="up" class="vote1" id="<?php echo $id_pregunta."-".$id_respuesta; ?>-1" name="mod_up">Accept</a>
```

But if I click one more time in Accept's link only shows the gif () And doesn't update the database and doesn't show the new question&answer.

How must I use .live()? or .delegate()? or what i need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer .delegate. Here's an interesting article about .delegate and .live:

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

Here's also what you need to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(document).delegate('.vote, .vote1', 'click', function()
    {
        //code
    });
});
```

Comment: i was writing a big LoL with many o's. But someone will flag it and my poor 19 coins will go to trash. Really thanks. (Love you)

Answer (score 4):

Use `jQuery` `live` instead of `click`.

```
$(".vote, .vote1").live('click', function(){

.......
......


});
```

Comment: i did, and bind too.$(document).ready(function()
{

$(".vote, .vote1").live(function(){

{

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name"); .... and ... This doesn't work

Comment: If i click it the first time i'm redirected to home. Don't know why.

Comment: If i chnage <a href="" to <a href="moderation" load a new question and answer, but doesn't update anything. Is like a "normal" link.

Comment: I voted up because you were helping too much @Shankar here and others posts. But one thing, in official documentation i saw this: $('.clickme').live('click', function() {

Comment: Thanks @Jorge I actually had missed the event type `click` which is the first argument of `live` method. That was in a hurry :)